# PHP Test of empty condition test yields inconsistent results

Tags: php, file-exists, string

I'm pulling in an XML file and performing various massaging of data.  I assigned an element (which has no data) to a variable and tested whether the variable is empty.  The test was false.  Not sure why, I tested the element directly and it passed as true.  Baffled by this, I put the variable through several conditions, just to see what I was dealing with.  This has left me perplexed, as the results seem entirely inconsistent to me.
The code I put this through is as follows:

```
$xmldata = simplexml_load_file('data.xml');
$picture = $person->picturefile;       <--picturefile is empty
if (!empty($person->picturefile)) {
    echo "picture is not empty";
    } else {
    echo "picture is empty";
    }

if (!empty($picture)) {
    echo "picture is not empty";
    } else {
    echo "picture is empty";
    }

$tempfile = "members/$picture";
if (file_exists($tempfile)) {
   echo "<div class=mgridimg><img src=$tempfile></div>";
}
```

The test of the xml path yields a false condition (picture is empty), but the test of the variable yields a true condition (picture is not empty).
I put the variable through a strlen test and it showed strlen = 0.

From the xml file, $picture, when populated, has a file name.
Just as baffling, although $picture is empty, the file_exists test passes as true.
I've also verified that in the above test, $tempfile contains a value of "members/".
I can't make sense of the empty test of the variable or the file_exists test.
I can code around this, but am wondering why I am seeing what I'm seeing.
Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried dropping it in a hex editor, or an ascii converter to see if there is some weird control character? http://www.krisl.net/cgi-bin/ascbin.pl

Comment: I put in a trim while assigning the variable ($picture) from the xml element and now it returns as empty when it is empty. It still isn't clear why it needs to be trimmed.  I'm guessing that on assigning an empty element from the xml file to a variable, a null character is inserted, which causes the empty test to not pass. It doesn't make sense, but it's all I can figure right now.

Answer (score 0):

For the first case it seems for me nearly impossible to be true. They both should be equal. Have you tried trimming?

For the file_exists function, if you don't want to be true on dir's, you should check for `!is_dir()`

E.g.:

```
var_dump(file_exists('New Folder/'));

var_dump(file_exists('New Folder/') && !is_dir('New Folder/'));

var_dump(file_exists('New Folder/New Text Document.txt') && !is_dir('New Folder/New Text Document.txt'));
```

outputs:

```
boolean true

boolean false

boolean true
```

Comment: I'm not trying to test whether the directory exists, I'm trying to test whether the file exists.  Since the filename is missing from the variable, I expect it should return false.

Comment: @user3465303 you don't get my point. You have pointed a directory and a filename after it. When the filename is BLANK, it will test only for the string `'members/'` or in my case for `'New Folder/'` which is folder, and the folder is file, that's why file_exists returns true. You want to exclude folders from this functions, right?

Comment: Just to further clarify, the expectation is that if the xml field has a value, then the file named should altready exist in a fixed directory.  I'm only testing to make sure it actually exists.

Comment: @user3465303 my three tests shows exactly your situation but with e a directory `New Folder` which contains a `.txt` files. In the first case I test if `file_exists()` when passing as parameter the `New folder/` and a blank file name (none). It returns TRUE (your case). Afterwards I put `!is_dir()`, so it returns FALSE (the result you expect). Afterwards I try with real file name `New Text Document.txt` in this directory and it returns `TRUE`. Also what you expect. You want to recieve `TRUE` only if the value is not EMPTY

Comment: ok, I got your point.  In that case, it looks like I should be using is_file().  I just tried that and it works as expected.  Thanks.  Now if I can better understand the empty test, that would be great.

Comment: I am not sure how you can result in one variable assigned to another and giving different result on `!empty()`. This might have worth searching it.

Comment: I just tried trimming the assigned variable ($picture) and it returns as empty, which is correct.  That said, it still isn't clear why it needs to be trimmed to yield the same result as the field it received it's value from.  It still doesn't make sense.